# Instance declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have these two functions:

```
primes = sieve [2..] 
    where
        sieve (p:xs) = p : sieve [x|x <- xs, x `mod` p > 0]
isPrime number = number /= 1 && null [x | x <- takeWhile (\x -> x < (ceiling . sqrt) number) primes, mod number x == 0]
```

The thing is that when I'm trying to load module which contains those functions, I see following error message:

```
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( euler37.hs, interpreted )

euler37.hs:6:70:
No instance for (RealFrac Int)
  arising from a use of `ceiling'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Int)
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `ceiling'
In the expression: ceiling . sqrt
In the second argument of `(<)', namely `(ceiling . sqrt) number'

euler37.hs:6:80:
No instance for (Floating Int)
  arising from a use of `sqrt'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Int)
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `sqrt'
In the expression: ceiling . sqrt
In the second argument of `(<)', namely `(ceiling . sqrt) number'
```

I really can't understand what's the problem, because when I'm trying to make a small function from piece of code, which, as far as I understand, cause these errors, right in ghci, like
    let f number x = x < (ceiling . sqrt) number
I don't see any error messages.

Comment: For the love of all that's holy, please don't use that algorithm to generate a list of primes. It's horribly, horribly bad. Yes, it's cute for its conciseness, but it should never be mentioned without a big fat warning **Don not use this. Ever!**

Comment: Thank you for good advice. I searched the Hackage and found 'primes' library. It goes with source code and a couple of links, so I can read all this stuff and make better implementation. :)

Comment: You can use the test x*x<=number.

Comment: @aga, `primes` is sort-of-decent, but [NumberSieves](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/NumberSieves) has a faster implementation and [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) is much faster still. I wouldn't recommend trying to understand `arithmoi`'s source though, I wrote it and have to think hard what's happening when I look at it.

Comment: @aga as a starting point, you don't need that "sieve" function at all, just filter the numbers by your `isPrime`, re-written as `noDivs factors n = foldr (\f r-> f*f>n || (rem n f /= 0 && r)) True factors`, so that `primes = 2 : 3 : filter (noDivs $ tail primes) [5,7..]`. Then, `isPrime n = n > 1 && noDivs primes n`.

Comment: @aga take a look also [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Tree_merging_with_Wheel). It's [twice faster](http://ideone.com/P0E81) than [the `primes`](http://ideone.com/t0ySN) [package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primes).

Comment: @Will For me that's slightly slower than the 'primes' package on 7.2.2 - more importantly, _it eats memory on 7.2.2_. The O'Neill sieve is about twice as fast in the region of 10^8 (scales a bit better than 'primes'), 'arithmoi/Heap' about 1.5 times as fast as O'Neill, the segmented Eratosthenes sieve using arrays about 16 times faster than O'Neill, scales better yet, at 10^9 the quotient is about 22. If you want speed and small memory usage, there's no way (yet) around mutable arrays.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've tried it on Ideone.com - these were also the links I provided. It uses 6.8.1 I think. The memory is also near-constant there. Of course I didn't intend to make a comprehensive claim about speed, it was not my intention. My main concern is to have simple functional code, which is reasonably fast. Empirical O(n^1.2) is reasonable, even if with larger constant factor. Even the simplest (but optimal) trial division is good enough for the first 100,000 primes or so. But the real stuff of course is much more complex - your package must be used then etc.

Comment: @DanielFischer btw what if Haskell could (correctly IMO) recognize the uniqueness in case where array update is in tail call position, and use destructive update in [such a case](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array)? Then we'd have benefits of mutable arrays while formally still working with immutable ones. You've made a titanic effort with arithmoi, wouldn't it be "better" to have a "smart enough" compiler to make optimizations for a simple and functional high-level code, ultimately? :) Wasn't *this* the original premise of functional/logical programming ? :)

Comment: @Will The point was that performance characteristics differ with OS and compiler and to provide additional data points. Since ideone's 6.8.2 is **ancient** (really, 6.10 is obsolete, 6.12 at the obsolescent/obsolete boundary, it's like using gcc-3.1), its characteristics are less relevant for the average user than ghc-7 characteristics. The most important thing was that the old attempts to prevent unwanted sharing now apparently fail, which is rather relevant, I'd say (and slightly disappointing, considering that getting the tree-fold to be a good memory citizen wasn't trivial).

Comment: @Daniel `-fno-cse` doesn't help anymore? this is indeed grave news then.

Comment: @Will Tail position or not isn't the problem, the compiler must be able to _prove_ that nobody else uses that version to convert it into using a mutable array. In the hundred or so years until compilers are smart enough to do that in all but very few cases, we have to take the burden of proof upon us. It would be nice if compilers were smart enough to do that and perform algorithmic improvements, but realistically, that's still a long time off.

Comment: @Daniel but what about that specific case I linked? It looks simple enough for today's compilers to figure out. And then we'd force ourselves to writing in such a style, where needed. It wouldn't be the complete solution, but it *would* *still* be a (partial) solution. Which is better than nothing. Tail position is just the ultimate indicator for *re-use*, IMO. And iterated chain of tail-rec functions makes it clear nothing else uses [that array](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Accumulating_Array) - since the func is internal and receives explicitly constructed array.

Comment: @aga: You should read http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: @Will In the specific case you linked, if you use an _unboxed_ array (`UArray Int Bool`), GHC does figure it out and it doesn't do too badly (much better than priority queue or treefold for a while) - I tried 6.12.3 and 7.2.2. It's of course much slower than a segmented sieve that fits into the L2 cache (and cache locality is why PQ and TF seemingly scale better than a monolithic sieve once you get to large ranges), and that transformation would be really hard for a compiler :)

Comment: @Daniel very interesting, thanks for checking all of this! :) yes, a compiler that could figure out segmentation all by itself could probably learn Chinese all by itself too, while sitting in a dark windowless room. :)

Comment: @Landei unfortunately that article can be very confusing. It misses key points about original sieve, and it misses the key reason for Turner's code's inefficiency. I'd recommend starting from e.g. [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) or even (shameless plug) [haskellwiki page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers).

Comment: @Daniel wow!! - I should've said. 2.5x faster to find a 100,000-th prime than TF with 2-3-5-7 wheel (and that's working with odds)! Improving empirical complexity from n^1.75 to n^1.23! My, what one type annotation can do. Thanks!!

Comment: (correction: the array code seems to run at `n^1.35` empirical complexity, for `n` primes produced. The closer to optimal PQ or TF both run at just above `n^1.2`. It still is a gigantic improvement compared to the simple immutable array.)

Comment: **news update**: Ideone.com now works with ghc-7.4.1, and there is no memory problem there running [primes generation code from haskellwiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Tree_merging_with_Wheel), test entry here: http://ideone.com/n3XzZY . The tree-fold is a "good memory citizen" yet again! :) (re: [comment by @Daniel Fischer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114439/instance-declaration-in-haskell#comment11473273_9114439) above).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `primes` is a list of Integers (due to your use of `mod`), but `sqrt` operates on floating-point numbers. If you do `x < (ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral) number`, then it'll work fine. `fromIntegral` just converts an integral number into any other numeric type:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

In this case, since you don't specify any specific floating-point type to convert to, it'll default to using Double values to compute the square root. You could specify another type by changing `fromIntegral` to something like `(fromIntegral :: Integer -> Float)`.

The reason you don't see this error in GHCi is because your conditional is fine; it just works on different types to the ones you're using here. Just verifying that a piece of code is correct in isolation isn't enough; for it to pass the type checker, it has to make sense in context too.

You might want to consider using an [integer square root algorithm](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generic_number_type#squareRoot) for accuracy.