# "True" pure functional doubly-linked list and Sharing of nodes

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, linked-list

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277176/lazy-vs-eager-evaluation-and-double-linked-list-building/9283057#9283057) I was introduced to [this OCaml code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Doubly-linked_list/Element_definition#Functional) which in Haskell can be written as:

```
data DL a = DL [a] a [a]

create [] = error "empty list"
create (x:xs) = DL [] x xs

next (DL pr x (h:tl)) = DL (x:pr) h tl
next _ = error "end of dlist"

prev (DL (p:pr) x tl) = DL pr p (x:tl)
prev _ = error "start of dlist"
```

which I though was *not* a proper doubly-linked list implementation, as it creates new storage on traversal. OTOH there's [this Haskell code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Doubly-Linked_List_%28traversal%29#Haskell):

```
data DList a = Leaf | Node { prev::(DList a), elt::a, next::(DList a) }

create = go Leaf
  where go _    []     = Leaf
        go prev (x:xs) = current
            where current = Node prev x next
                  next    = go current xs
```

Can we say that it is *only this* code that's *true* dl-list?

Can we rely on this code to introduce true sharing of nodes of the dl-list, so that no new storage is created on traversal?

**Is the same-named variable in Haskell always referring to *the same "thing"* or might separate occurrences of the same-named variable refer to separate copy of the same thing?** (edited to add emphasis).

Comment: The first implementation is what is known as a _Zipper_; arguably it can be for either singly- or doubly-linked lists.  However, it is not a list implementation in its own right.

Comment: If you read the Haskell report carefully, you can't find a single paragraph on how data is represented. Keep in mind, that all kind of sharing is implementation dependent, though there are mostly only a few sensible ways to implement a certain feature.

Comment: Thank you for this question! I haven't satisfied with my, watching for this.

Comment: @FUZxxl I'll contend myself with anything firmly guaranteed by GHC. I don't think that without some specified behaviour sharing-wise we can reason in any way about efficiency.

Comment: If you say `let x = 5` and then refer to `x` multiple times it is very likely to refer to different copies of `5`.

Comment: @augustss that's ok, since `5` doesn't refer to anything further, unlike e.g. the `current` node, which the question really is about.

Comment: @WillNess GHC takes great care not to duplicate computations.  Once an expression has been computed to WHNF it may be duplicated without duplicating work.

Comment: @augustss thanks for that, but what about not duplicating *space*? Does it take great care for that too?  (btw there is such thing as [unwanted sharing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114439/instance-declaration-in-haskell#comment11473273_9114439), e.g. in primes production via tree-folded multiples-lists, but that's besides the point here).

Comment: I'm not 100% sure GHC is safe for space, but under normal circumstances it will not duplicate data.

Comment: @augustss thanks a lot. So I take from this that it is indeed reasonable to write code pretending that variables are named pointers, like they are in Scheme for instance (for non-atomic data of course).

Comment: @WillNess Yes, it's a reasonable mental model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that the latter is the "correct" implementation, yes.

I do not have facts with which to back that up, but it would seem to me, given my understanding of the GHC implementation, that the latter should work how you'd expect a double-linked list to work.

Comment: thanks! I'd like to have certainty, especially about my last question. :)

Comment: @WillNess I believe that's an implementation issue, but GHC does use pointer-based representation under the hood to represent the same thing (e.g. in `xs++ys`, the original `ys` value is used as the end of the new combined list).

Answer (score 6):

You can visualise how the memory layout of your data structure looks using a package called vacuum-cairo. Install from hackage with `cabal install vacuum-cairo` then you should be able to verify the difference in the two structures by something like this in GHCi:

```
> import System.Vacuum.Cairo
> view $ create [1..5]
```

There you can see the nodes are shared using the DList where as DL is two lists with an element in between (As pointed out, this is kind of Zipper).

Note: This is GHC specific, a different implementation might represent the data in memory differently, but this would be typical.

Comment: thanks, I understand how it *supposed* to be. But it was suggested (in the post to which the first word in my question links) that sharing is not guaranteed. Then, how the structure is supposed to be, and how `cairo` would show it to me, will not necessarily be  how it is in reality. I want to know, is there a guarantee at least that same named var is always pointing to the same thing in memory, in whatever implementation?

Comment: Yes, otherwise an example like this won't work: `(x, xs) = let y = replicate 10 x in (length y, y)`

Comment: I think it still would work, since there's no cycles in the dependency flow in your example.

Comment: @WillNess as FUZxxl stated, the Haskell Report does not specify sharing behavior. GHC typically works as you expect, and when it doesn't, it's typically a very small deviation from what you would expect. Given the way Haskell is specified, you as the programmer should not be able to tell the difference between sharing implementations (value-wise), except perhaps the time it takes to perform computations.

Comment: @DanBurton thanks! time *and* space ... But it makes me a bit uneasy. I don't like the word "typically" or "usually", I like "guaranteed". It makes me in control, instead of being at the mercy of. :) And if Haskell The Language goes to such lengths *not* to commit to anything, and pretend that it is equational specifications that we write and not programs, let it indeed let us get away with equational high-level specs, and *outdo* our expectations and perform all the transformations leading to the fastest and leanest code, all by itself. :) :) Then I'd gladly accept the lack of spec'ns. :)

Comment: @WillNess most languages can make guarantees about performance, while Haskell is a little more focused towards guarantees of correctness. Though, by not specifying sharing, the Haskell language makes a guarantee to the compiler that pointer equality cannot be inspected, and thus the compiler may make optimizations based on that. Most languages *do* specify that pointer equality matters, and so the compilers are constrained in what they can do when optimizing code dealing with pointers. The same goes for immutable data; Haskell and its compilers makes different tradeoffs than most languages do.